# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Invoke Worklight Procedure option not found in Run As context menu

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-adapters

I am unable to debug my adapter as I am unable to see the Invoke Worklight Procedure option in my Run As. In 5.0.6 I had that option, but I don't see this in my upgrade.

[image: You can see my Run Configurations with no Inovoke Worklight procedures]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there alright:

[image]

1. Make sure you have right-clicked your adapter and not some other folder.
2. Try with a new workspace.
3. Try un-installing and then re-installing the Worklight Studio plug-in.

I am betting on option 2.

Comment: It worked when I create a new workspace. There are a few consistency issues with IBM WL 5.0.6 and 6.0.0.

Comment: A lot of the run options no longer exist in the run as configuration menu